# Select statement Displaying incorrect results

Tags: c#, sql

I implemented a search of my nested gridview, and All is working well. But when the gridview loads, it is displaying duplicate rows in the parent table.

[image]

As you can see in the picture, There are 2 books under the CourseID of AC107. But my Gridview is displaying a row for each textbook in the course. I have messed with this select statement and anyway I alter it to see if anything works, the gridview doesnt load.

```
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            //i'm using a datatable for storing all the data 
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            string query = "select * from Course inner join textBooks on textBooks.CourseID = Course.CourseID";

            //wrapping in 'using' means the connection is closed an disposed when done 
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["HUTDMSConnectionString"].ToString()))
            using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, connection))
            {
                try
                {
                    //fill the datatable with the contents from the database 
                    adapter.Fill(dt);
                }
                catch
                {
                }
            }

            //save the datatable into a viewstate for later use 
            ViewState["allBooks"] = dt;

            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

Below is a layout of my data tables.

[image]

Comment: Never use an empty try-catch.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your SQL query not fetching you the duplicate rows, use `ROW_NUMBER()` function and see how it works like (assuming you are using `SQL Server` since you are using `SqlConnection` provider class)

```
SELECT * FROM (
select Course.*,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Course.CourseID ORDER BY Course.CourseID) AS rn  
from Course 
inner join textBooks 
on textBooks.CourseID = Course.CourseID ) xxx
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Comment: Do I just throw this in the quote where my current query is?

Comment: Yes exactly ... replace your current query with this

Comment: receiving this error: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'thirteenISBN'.

Comment: @user3487671, that I am not sure off but in outer query don't do select * since your datatable will not have a column for `rn` column. In outer query do explicutely select the column saying select col1,col2,col3....